# How many different URLs in a project

Tags: url

We are currently evaluating different cookie consent solutions considering its price models and therefore we need to know the amount of "active" URLs in our Craft multisite installation.

**Does Craft somewhere cache or save complete URLs which I could count?**

*(I'm not sure if it does but since Craft always makes sure that URLs are unique I have hope that it does.)*

Comment: Without delving into the database, can't you just count how many URL-enabled elements you have, multiplied by the number of sites?

Comment: With Commerce and its product variants, not all entries available in all languages and so on, this might be inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at Luke Peter's Sitemap solution. This is a script that generates your sitemap. You can modify it to fit your need and just output a list of URLs.

[Generate an XML Sitemap in Craft CMS](https://lukepeters.me/blog/generate-an-xml-sitemap-in-craft-cms)

```
{# Create an empty array for all published entries #}
{% set entry_list = [] %}

{# Create a URI exclusion list for entries you don't want in the sitemap #}
{% set exclusions = ["blog/unlisted-blog-post", "thank-you-page"] %}

{# Get all sections (singles, channels, and structures) #}
{% set sections = craft.app.sections.allSections %}

{# Loop through each section #}
{% for section in sections %}

  {# Get all entries of this section type, but only if they're published and have a URL #}
  {% set entries = craft.entries.sectionId(section.id).status("live").uri("not ''").all() %}

  {# Merge these entries into the main list #}
  {% set entry_list = entry_list|merge(entries) %}
  
{% endfor %}

{#
  Loop through all published entries to create the sitemap markup.
  Skip any entries with a URI that appears in the exclusions list.
#}
<ul>
{% for entry in entry_list if entry.uri not in exclusions %}
  <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.url }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Most SEO Plugins that generate a Sitemap might solve this problem as well.